# How an Angular asynchronous pipe works

Tags: angular, typescript, async-pipe

I am developing an Angular application. The issue is that my template displays before a request for a variable (`annonces`) in the corresponding component returns its value. So I have to use an `async` pipe. I tried to use it, but the variable in the template does not refresh and I have no result for an `*ngFor` directive

Here is the component

```
export class AppListProduitImmobilierComponent implements OnInit {

  public annonces: Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]>
.................
.................
  ngOnInit() {
    this.preloadData();  // this function does a pre-request and afterwards call loadData(search)
................
...............
    loadData(search: Search) {
      this.annonces = this.service.getListProduitImmobilierDTO(this.pagesize, this.page, search);
```

The part of the template is the following:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let annonce of annonces | async; let i = index" class="pointer">
```

And the service is the following:

```
  getListProduitImmobilierDTO(pagesize: number, page: number, search: Search): Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = { headers: headers };
    search.page = page;
    search.pageSize = pagesize;
    return this.http.post<Search>('/api/produitimmobilier/all', JSON.stringify(search), options).pipe(map((search: Search) => search.result as ProduitImmobilierDTO[]));
  }
```

Comment: What is being printed in the console when you add `this.annonces = this.annonces.pipe(tap(dtos => console.log('received the dtos:", dtos));` Do you see the request being sent in your network dev tools? What does the response body look like?

Comment: Check the response you are getting from API.

Comment: When I add this.annonces = this.annonces.pipe(tap(dtos => console.log('received the dtos:", dtos));, nothing is printed. The post isn't even made. I checked in the network tab. Previously, when I subscribed to the service request, there was a POST request made. I add that I have no error

Comment: That can mean two things: loadDate() is never called, or the mat-card is never displayed (because it's inside an ngIf with a false condition, for example). Use your debugger to find out.

Comment: I debugged: loadData() is called and there is no condition to hide or ignore mat-card. I think it is related to the fact that I make a post request, but found nothing on internet

Comment: After closing firefox and re-open it, it worked. The POST request hit the server in aleatory time, and the time is quite long between each response. After some POST response and a while, it didn't work again. So, the code work, but there must be some tuning to do or something to change in order to have a quick response from the server. The issue is that the request does not fire immediately, but has a delay which can be very, very long. Do you see what to do

Answer (score 0):

This morning, I turned on my computer and change the code to make a normal request (that is not using async pipe)

loadData() function became the following

```
public annonces: ProduitImmobilierDTO[];
loadData(search: Search) {
  console.log('LOADDATA is called');
  this.service.getListProduitImmobilierDTO(this.pageSize, this.page, search).subscribe(
    articles => {this.annonces = articles; this.collectionSize = articles[0].collectionSize; console.log('this.annonces'); console.log(this.annonces)},
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

the relevant template using *ngFor became the following

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let annonce of annonces; let i = index"  class="pointer">
```

And I can see that the POST request is made almost immediately, but the template does not refresh (that's why I tried asynchronous pipe) immediately, but after a while. So the difference between using not async pipe and using async pipe is that when not using async pipe, the request POST is made immediately but there is a latency delay before the template updates. I thought that using async pipe, the template updates immediately when the POST request was fired, but the issue with this choice is that the POST request hit the server after a very, very long delay. So I am still blocked: my aim is to interact immediately between client and server side

Comment: what I can tell is when I close my browser and re-open it, it works and this, even if I don't use async pipe

Answer (score 0):

As I have my POST request that works (without async pipe), I try to build an observable from the result of the request and use it in the template

in my component:

```
public annonces$: Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]> = new Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]>();

    loadData(search: Search) {
      this.service.getListProduitImmobilierDTO(this.pageSize, this.page, search).subscribe(
        articles => {this.annonces = articles; 
          this.annonces$ = of(articles);
          this.collectionSize = articles[0].collectionSize; console.log('this.annonces'); console.log(this.annonces)},
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }
```

And in the template

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let annonce of annonces$ | async; let i = index" class="pointer">
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

> ... The issue is that my template displays before a request for a variable
>   (annonces) in the corresponding component returns its value. **So I have
>   to use** an async pipe ...

That is incorrect.

you can hold your data in a variable and `*ngIf` the container to avoid errors.

**component:**

```
 public annonces: ProduitImmobilierDTO[];

 // ...
 ngOnInit() {
     this.service.getListProduitImmobilierDTO(this.pagesize, this.page, search)
         .subscribe(list => this.annonces = list);
 }
```

**template:**

```
<div *ngIf="annonces">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let annonce of annonces; let i = index">
<div>
```

that said, using the `|async` nowadays, is considered a best practice to avoid managing subscriptions manually, but eventually it's up to you.